# In Uno, if I play a Wild Card and pick a color, can I also play a card in that color?

Tags: uno

If I put down a Wild Card and choose a color, can I then also straight away play a card in that color?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can only play one card per turn.

*Let’s Play*

> On your turn...
>   Example: If the card on the Discard pile is a red 7, the player must put down a red card OR any color 7. **Alternatively, the player can put down a Wild Card**...

*Functions of Action Cards*

> Wild Card – When you play this card, you get to choose the color that continues
>   play (any color including the color in play before the Wild card was laid down)...

Here's a great place to read the rules for yourself:
From mattel.com: [UNO Rules 2018](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GDJ85-Eng.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

No. After you play a card, the next player takes the next turn.

From [the rules](https://www.unorules.com/):

> Wild – This card represents all four colors, and can be placed on any card. The player has to state which color it will represent for the **next** player.

(emphasis added)

Comment: A source would be appreciated, like the answer of Ola Ström.